# Flask restful API urls

Tags: python, api, rest, flask, flask-restful

I am using Flask-RESTful(http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) in my project. Afrer reading some examples I understood that I will have only get, post, update etc methods in my Resource class. How can I make my own Resource class method with a unique url like it was in Flask with @app.route() decorator? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Look at quick start ([A Minimal API](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#a-minimal-api), [Resourceful Routing](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#resourceful-routing) and etc.):

```
api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')

api.add_resource(TodoSimple, '/<string:todo_id>')
```

Comment: I know it. But how can I create "hello_world" method and make a url for it in my Resource class?

Comment: To get method you can do something like this `resource_func = self.output(resource.as_view(endpoint))` (see https://github.com/twilio/flask-restful/blob/master/flask_restful/__init__.py#L244), to add resource with your Resource class better use decorator which will add resource with `api.add_resource`.

Answer (score -2):

I hope it helps

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        pass
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        pass
    else:
        pass
```