# Catch-All URL example in flask-restful also catching /

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

There is [a catch-all URL example for Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/57/):

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def catch_all(path):
    return 'You want path: %s' % path

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Decorators can be translated to the following to code look more similar to **Flask-RESTful** achieving the *same* functionality:

```
app.add_url_rule('/', 'catch_all', catch_all, defaults={'path': ''})
app.add_url_rule('/<path:path>', 'catch_all', catch_all, defaults={'path': ''})
```

If I'm right, this can be further translated to an equivalent **Flask-RESTful** app (at least debuging shows it creates the same URL routes):

```
class RESTapp(Resource):
    def get(self, path):
        # do get something

api.add_resource(RESTapp, '/', '/<path:path>', defaults={'path': ''})
```

The problem is that this app redirects all URLs to / and I can not get the requested path in get() function. I want to handle all paths ( / and '/') in the same function as in Flask, but using Flask-RESTful.

Similar questions:

- [Catch-All URL in flask-restful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627804/catch-all-url-in-flask-restful) The Asker **does not want to catch /** or at least not in the same functions as other URL-s.
- [Flask restful API urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19636532/flask-restful-api-urls) The Answerer **proposes two classess as two resources**. I have to initialize the class through `resource_class_kwargs` keyword argument and **I want to keep only one instance, so it will not be good for me**.

What I've tried:

- Create two `add_resource` calls for the same class. It end with error.
- Debug `add_resource`. It shows that it creates a resource view function from the Endpoint and that is given to the `add_url_rule` function. Else it works the same as the two subsequent `add_url_rule` functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By trial and error I've figured out the solution, which is neither documented nor looks like to the expected way of doing it (simmilarly as in Flask, showed in the question).

**One must supply a Pythonic default argument to `get()` and other functions: `get(stuff='DEF_VAL')`**

Full example which is working:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class RESTapp(Resource):

    @staticmethod
    def get(path=''):  # <-- You should provide the default here not in api.add_resource()!
        return 'You want path: \'%s\'' % path  # do get something


api.add_resource(RESTapp, '/', '/<path:path>')  # Here just the URLs must be the arguments!


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```